# Is it possible to check the condition of a value of an object and JUST return the key?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects

I have an object of letters and numbers inside of a function. This function takes in an array of numbers and I'm running a for in loop that iterates over the object and checks a condition. If any of the numbers in the array match any of the values in the object, return *just* the *key* to that value.

So If I pass in `switcher(['26'])`, it should return 'a'. Is this possible?

```
function switcher(x){
const letters = {
  a: '26',
  b: '25',
  c: '24',
  d: '23',
  e: '22',
  f: '21',
  g: '20',
  h: '19',
  i: '18',
  j: '17',
  k: '16',
  l: '15',
  m: '14',
  n: '13',
  o: '12',
  p: '11',
  q: '10',
  r: '9',
  s: '8',
  t: '7',
  u: '6',
  v: '5',
  w: '4',
  x: '3',
  y: '2',
  z: '1'
};
}
```

I have attempted to do this via the ES6 `map()` method, but I am unsure as to what to put in my if statement.. Here is what I have so far:

```
return x.map(function(number){
  let keys = Object.keys(letters);
  for(var key in letters){
    if(letters[key] === number){
    }
  }
 });
}
```

Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: why not just have the array the other way round, with the numbers as the key and the letters as the value? Then, in your example, you could simply request `letters[26]` and it would return "a", with no further messing about required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `Object.keys` and `Array#find` to get the `key` of the matched `value`.

```js
const letters = {a:'26',b:'25',c:'24',d:'23',e:'22',f:'21',g:'20',h:'19',i:'18',j:'17',k:'16',l:'15',m:'14',n:'13',o:'12',p:'11',q:'10',r:'9',s:'8',t:'7',u:'6',v:'5',w:'4',x:'3',y:'2',z:'1'};

function switcher(num){
  var res = Object.keys(letters).find(v => letters[v] == num);
  return res;
}

console.log(switcher('26'));
console.log(switcher('9'));
```

Comment: May be worth noting that `.find` is ES6 so it will not work on older environments.

Comment: @loganfsmyth Yeah, it may not work on very old browsers, like IE7 or whatsoever.

Comment: It doesn't work on any version of IE. Edge is the first Microsoft browser to support it. You'd have to load a polyfill for IE.

Comment: IE? That still exists? :P

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to just swap the key/value pairs, and work with that.

If you want the code to make the swap, you can do it in a one-shot operation (assigned to `numbers` Map). This is ES6 code:

```js
const letters = {a:'26',b:'25',c:'24',d:'23',e:'22',f:'21',g:'20',h:'19',i:'18',j:'17',k:'16',l:'15',m:'14',n:'13',o:'12',p:'11',q:'10',r:'9',s:'8',t:'7',u:'6',v:'5',w:'4',x:'3',y:'2',z:'1'};
const numbers = new Map(Object.keys(letters).map( k => ([letters[k], k])));

console.log(numbers.get('26'));
console.log(numbers.get('9'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `return key;`

```js
function switcher(x) {
  const letters = {
    a: '26',
    b: '25',
    c: '24',
    d: '23',
    e: '22',
    f: '21',
    g: '20',
    h: '19',
    i: '18',
    j: '17',
    k: '16',
    l: '15',
    m: '14',
    n: '13',
    o: '12',
    p: '11',
    q: '10',
    r: '9',
    s: '8',
    t: '7',
    u: '6',
    v: '5',
    w: '4',
    x: '3',
    y: '2',
    z: '1'
  };
  return x.map(function(number) {
    let keys = Object.keys(letters);
    for (var key in letters) {
      if (letters[key] === number) {
        return key;
      }
    }
  });
}
console.log(switcher(['26']));
```

But if you're going to do this frequently, the other answers with the inverted object are better.

Answer (score 1):

One might also do as;

```js
function switcher(x){
var letters = {
    a: '26',
    b: '25',
    c: '24',
    d: '23',
    e: '22',
    f: '21',
    g: '20',
    h: '19',
    i: '18',
    j: '17',
    k: '16',
    l: '15',
    m: '14',
    n: '13',
    o: '12',
    p: '11',
    q: '10',
    r: '9',
    s: '8',
    t: '7',
    u: '6',
    v: '5',
    w: '4',
    x: '3',
    y: '2',
    z: '1'
  };
    for (var k in letters) if (letters[k] === x) return k;
    return undefined;
}

console.log(switcher("14"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to presume from the fact that you are searching using an array that you may want more than one result. For example, `["26", "5"]` should return `["a", "v"]`.

You can do this with a one-liner:

```js
const letters = {a:'26',b:'25',c:'24',d:'23',e:'22',f:'21',g:'20',h:'19',i:'18',j:'17',k:'16',l:'15',m:'14',n:'13',o:'12',p:'11',q:'10',r:'9',s:'8',t:'7',u:'6',v:'5',w:'4',x:'3',y:'2',z:'1'};

const search = ["26", "5"];
const results = Object.entries(letters).filter(l => search.includes(l[1])).map(l => l[0]);

console.log(results);
```

This is post-ES6 code. ([`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) is ES2016; [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) is ES2017.) It's easily polyfillable, however.

[`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) makes an array where each property of the object is an element in the array in the format `[key, value]`, such as `["a", "26"]`. We then filter them by testing to see if our search array [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) the element. We then use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to get just the second element from each array, i.e. the values from the original array.

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need that lookup table `letters` (which is the wrong way round for your purpose anyway). Just use [`charCodeAt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt) and [`fromCharCode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode) for converting letters to numbers and back:

```
function switcher(x) {
   return x.map(function(code) {
       return x > 0 && x <= 26 ? String.fromCharCode(123-x) : "";
   });
}
console.log(switcher([26, 1])); // ["a", "z"]
```